# Tuple where a succeeding element's type is dependent on the value of a preceding element

Tags: typescript, generics, types, tuples

I think I have a simple question, but I also am not sure that this is possible in TypeScript.

Essentially I want to define a tuple type which has two elements and the second element depends on the value of the first.

As an example of this, I want to make a type where the first tuple element is a key of an interface, and the second tuple element is then tied to the type of that property. For example:

```
interface ExampleI {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

const one: KeyedTuple<ExampleI> = ["a", 34]; // good
const two: KeyedTuple<ExampleI> = ["a", "not a number"]; // bad
const three: KeyedTuple<ExampleI> = ["b", 47]; // bad
```

I tried to do the following:

```
type KeyedTuple<T, K extends keyof T> = [K, T[K]];
```

This almost works, but the compiler only considers the type of `K`, not the value of `K`, so the second element *always* has type `number | string`.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually I think you want `KeyedTuple<T>` to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `[K, T[K]]` tuples for all `K` in `keyof T`.  This can be achieved with [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) types, like this:

```
type KeyedTuple<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];
```

Let's test it:

```
interface ExampleI {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

type KeyedTupleExampleI = KeyedTuple<ExampleI>;
// type KeyedTupleExampleI = ["a", number] | ["b", string]
```

It gives you exactly the behavior you were asking for:

```
const one: KeyedTuple<ExampleI> = ["a", 34]; // okay
const two: KeyedTuple<ExampleI> = ["a", "not a number"]; // error
const three: KeyedTuple<ExampleI> = ["b", 47]; // error
```

Furthermore, since assignments act as [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) on union types, the compiler will remember which key/value pair a variable is:

```
one[1].toFixed(); // okay, remembers one[1] is a number
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbCASWQG8AoZZOALmRAFcsAjaAbguSdoGcwpQA5uwC+ZMmACeOFAGkIEiABMAKvXwQAPMoB8yALylkAbRnJQyANbyA9jGTKAurRMAaeyYcPkwo1Ym37B3ZxKVl5JVV1DGx1YgM5BRU1Ag1o3AJCbXYAemzkSWlkBIjkiDTY-WMAIjgqtwZmaC8AH2qmOuRefhABBzEEaxBeZEGIWmKk9VTMdKJdAyMajoBmABYg5FyRizgJMgGhsHyAd2tx8MmU8oz56tq3KpBrI7g6RhYoKo2t6ChrKH2g2GYAAFlAIGMihdIlcZrFbot2m5VgB2b55X7-MSjIwARgcADowNYAGLAdBKAAUAEpWJs8tYdhIgA)

Comment: This does solve the example I gave exactly. Unfortunately though, that was a simplified version of my problem. In a more complex instance, I don't think it would be feasible to create a union of every possible type

Comment: A [mcve] of the issue that you don't think this addresses would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
const keyedTuple = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): [T, T[K]] => {
    return [obj, obj[key]]
}

interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number
}
declare const Person: IPerson
const test = keyedTuple(Person, "name") // [Person, string]
```

Is one way to achieve this, i'm more in favor of having a function to achieve this than remembering to write out a colon or "as" cast to the correct type.

Your code wont work unless the key is known it can't be inferred from a variable but can be inferred from a function.

IE Your code would have to change to something like `ObjKeyed<OBJ, KEY> = [Obj, Key]`

EDIT: With types:

```
type KeyedTuple<T, K extends keyof T> = [K, T[K]];

interface ExampleI {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

const one: KeyedTuple<ExampleI, "a"> = ["a", 34]; // good
const two: KeyedTuple<ExampleI, "a"> = ["a", "not a number"]; // bad
const three: KeyedTuple<ExampleI, "b"> = ["b", 47]; // bad
```

Comment: While this behavior is similar to what I am describing, a function is not equivalent to a type and can't be used in any of the same places.

Comment: added edit hope this helps, it wont be possible to infer the key in a variable like i said in the above comment so you will have to add it to the type hardcoded